What is the meaning of velocity in Bohmian trajectories?
Given a quantum particle of mass $m$ with state
$$\psi=\exp(ip_1 x/\hbar)+\exp(ip_2 x/\hbar)$$
all of their Bohmian trajectories have constant velocity $(p_1+p_2)/2$ However from the point of view of standard QM the particle have not definite momentum. Strange?

(Edit, not by OP:) For example, if we have $p_1=(p_x,p_y,0), \ p_2=(-p_x,p_y,0)$, the wave function is
$$\
\psi=\cos{\small \frac{p_x x}{\hbar}}\ e^{ip_y y/\hbar}
$$
and therefore the movement over the trajectories is: (see [guiding equation])
$$\hbar\ \text{Im} \frac{\nabla \psi}{\psi} = (0,p_y,0)
$$

If you have $p_1=(p_x,p_y,0), p_2=(-p_x,p_y,0)$, then the trajectories are indeed parallel and have equal velocity $p_y$. But they are concentrated in "lanes"
with density $\cos^2(p_x x/\hbar)$, as depicted here: https://i.sstatic.net/gwoi1XDI.png .
The silent assumption in your question is that momentum and velocity should be the same, but that is not true, momentum is essentially $d/dx$ so it measures the position dependence. And this state is not position-independent, it clearly depends on $x$, so it isn't an eigenstate with sharp value of momentum.

For starters, there are no particles in "standard QM". The standard formulation of quantum mechanics allows us to predict the distribution of quanta of energy in our detectors. That such a quantum has no defined momentum is completely false. One can (and we are) building position sensitive detectors that can detect energy, momentum and other conserved quantities at the same time. Momentum, in particular, is always conserved in a total absorption process. Momentum conservation laws do not allow for anything else to happen.

@LUIS MARTINEZ ALONSO : I added an example to your question, feel free to change the text or throw it out again!

Pilot wave theory has some counterintuitive results https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0793

Why is that strange?
